# Doctrine findOneBy invalid field name where field does exist

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine

I'm using Zend Framework with Doctrine. I'm creating an object, editing, then saving it. That works fine. However, when I later try to find that object based on one of the column values, Doctrine throws an error saying, "Message: Invalid field name to find by:". Notice there is no field name listed in the error message after the :.

My database table does have a column called status and the model base class does know about it. I'm using base classes and table classes in my setup.

Here is my code. The first section works fine and the record gets created in the database. Its the second line of the second section where the error gets thrown. I've tried different variations of the findBy calls, findBy('status', 'test1'), findByStatus('test1'), etc.

```
$credit = new Model_Credit();
$credit['buyer_id'] = 1;
$credit['status'] = 'test1';
$credit->save();

$creditTable = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Model_Buyer');
$credit = $creditTable->findOneByStatus('test1'); // dying here
$credit['status'] = 'test2';
$credit->save();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind! I hate when you see the answer right after posting a big long question. In the second section I referred to a different model (Model_Buyer) instead of Model_Credit.